# How to check if 3 Image controls have the same image source

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 **Image** controls that are named: slot1, slot2 and slot3. If I want to check that slot1, slot2 and slot3 have the same image source, I do this:

```
if (slot1.Source == slot2.Source && slot2.Source == slot3.Source && slot3.Source == slot1.Source)
{
    MessageBox.Show("sss");
}
```

But it doesn't show me the message box. I tried different methods but they didn't show the message box too. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How did you define the source?

Comment: As a note, the third comparison is redundant. If a==b and b==c then a==c is always true.

Comment: @grek40 I put Console.WriteLine(slot1.Source) and same for all slots and it showed "pack://application:,,,/Anime Clicker;component/Images/heroFaceImages/GohanFace.png" 3 times

Comment: That was not the question. Once again, how do you *set* the Source properties of the Image controls?

Comment: @Clemens Well I have for example "Images/heroFaceImages/GokuFace.png" and i set it in Designer like so: Properties>Source>GokuFace.png. EDIT: In code i do it like so: slot.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/heroFaceImages/GokuFace.png", UriKind.Relative));

Comment: If you assign two different BitmapImages to the Source property of two Image controls, they will not compare equal, even if their source Uri is the same. As was shown in a now deleted answer, you could simply cast the Sources to BitmapImage and compare their UriSources. Maybe user derape will undelete their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I put `Console.WriteLine(slot1.Source)` and same for all slots and it showed `"pack://application:,,,/Anime Clicker;component/Images/heroFaceImages/GohanFace.png"` 3 times

Compare the string representations then:

```
if (slot1.Source != null && slot2.Source != null && slot3.Source != null 
    && slot1.Source.ToString() == slot2.Source.ToString()
    && slot2.Source.ToString() == slot3.Source.ToString())
{
    MessageBox.Show("sss");
}
```

Comment: When I have 3 different images it still shows message box.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Did you see Clemens' edit? You should compare the Source.ToString() property of each Image.

Comment: It's worth to note that this not only works when the Source property is explicitly assigned to a BitmapImage, but also when its assigned to an URI string in XAML, and built-in type conversion creates a BitmapFrame from that string.

Comment: However, it only works for the same image source as in the exact same resolved URI, not for every image source that refers to the same Image (eg. absolute vs relative path). The answer is spot on, just don't expect string comparison to do anything magical :)